# Error while enabling the rabbitmq_management plugin

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am new user of rabbitmq . I have installed Erlang and Rabbitmq on an 64-bit windows machine . The environment variables are set properly.
When I try to enable the rabbitmq_management plugin from the command prompt I get the following error : (Note running the command on an elevated cmd prompt )

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@Failed... failed.

Is there any step that I am missing ?

Comment: it is an `.erlang.cookie` problem, Please read here https://www.rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure rabbitmq-server is in running status when executing the command for enabling the rabbitmq_management plugin.

If still not working, upgrade your Erlang to latest version and try again.

Comment: I am using 18.2.1 version of Erlang and the rabbit-mq server is running before enabling the management plugin . The issue still exists